# The simplest way to switch on keyboard emojis on php

Tags: php, html, emoji

I want to enable keyboard emojis in php.I have looked for a lot of plugins but none of them worked.Im looking for simple converter that converts emoji to code and when I fetch data convert to html. Is there any plugin like I said?
it display when I `var_dump()` data:

```
string(41) //but it shows empty
```

Comment: use utf8_encode() function to display emoji.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37218910/utf8-encode-and-emoji

Answer (score 1):

In php7.* versions has support for **Unicode codepoint escape syntax** . This will help to populate standard emojis.

for example

```
echo “\u{1F60D}”; // outputs
```

Demo in online: https://3v4l.org/uDbiu